# easy visualization of usage statistics (web app)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some usage queries for my web app's database, the results of which I want to display graphically. Is there an easy-to-use API that exists for this purpose?

I want to show things like average query-time per user (a small user-base), average query time per day, and things like that. I think it would be cool to show these on a two-axis graph.

I am displaying this data on my site, so a jQuery/Javascript/HTML solution for rendering information into graphs would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionCharts has easy to use graphs - nice xml interface - but not free.

edit:

this is a [good link](http://insideria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html) for several options:

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) can be handy for this kind of thing. If you want your own hosted solution, [High Charts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of good javascript/jquery charting controls here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+charting+library